# What is the difference between an event and the method in jquery

Tags: jquery

Please help, I can not find a proper difference between an event and method in jQuery. Are both mean the same? Or there is some difference in both terms. For example:

`$('.btn-warning').click(function(){ $('<li class="list-group-item">').text('Appended item' + i).appendTo('.list-group');
});`

Is this a method or an event? Because `click` is an event, but it is also a function. This is why I am confused.

Comment: An event is an action: resize, onchange, click, .... which executes a method

Comment: Thanks, :-) what a brief explanation that explains the difference. I will keep it in mind. A method is called when an event is occur.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both are different.

A method is nothing but a function which executes something in it when called. it can be called any time.

A event is a result of a action performed by the user like click, hover, drag, re-size etc.

There are event handlers. Basically these are methods that are called when a event happens.

Hope you understand. What you referred to here is a event handler I guess.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was very confused about these terms. Yes, I understood it. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

First off, jQuery is a library written in JavaScript. The question should be: What is the difference between an event and method in JavaScript?

Anyway, an event occurs when a user does something on your page, e.g. clicks a link. You can then catch this event and respond to it (e.g. by showing or hiding an element).

There are some events that aren't directly caused by the user: the load event that fires when a page has been loaded, for instance.

You can read more about events here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

A method, on the other hand, is a function associated with an object, or, put another way, a property of an object that is a function.

```
var myObj = {
  myMethod: function(params) {
    // ...do something
  }
};
```

You can read more about methods here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_methods

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, and yes I will definitely keep it in mind. I am new into JavaScript and jQuery, I am learning right now. So all your answers will help me a lot.